# How to access the dynamic form url in Cypress which has got an external attribute?

Tags: javascript, cypress

In my app, I need to create a form and then activate that form, only after activating the form, I will get the new form dynamic 'url' which has got an attribute rel="external". Since the url is opening in a external tab/link, how to remove that attribute and access the url within Cypress limits. The below code doesn't work,

note: *I have rewrite the test, as I was using cy.visit() multiple time in my test and Cypress doesn't allow to use cy.visit() twice for the same domain*

```html
<div id="main">
<div id="mainid">
<p>Live Action:
<a href="https://sometestsite.com/form/et24yetwefff  rel="external"></a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

```
cy.wait(2000)
        Cypress.$('#main-inner > p > a').removeAttr("rel")
        cy.get('p > a').last()
           .should('have.attr', 'href')
            .then((href) => {
             console.log(href);
             cy.visit(href)
             cy.wait(2000)
             ........// test continues type values in text field and submit the form
          })
```

Comment: What do you mean activate the form? Is the `href` present from the start of the test, or not?

Comment: Will make it more clear, `activate` the form is one of the work flow process in our application. Only after activating,  the `dynamic` form url will be available and href will be present inside.

Comment: Hard to say what you're doing wrong since you're not showing all the code. Assuming the cypress code you posted is is run after "activating" the form, I don't see a problem. WTBS, the `Cypress.$('#main-inner > p > a').removeAttr("rel")` is synchronous and will run *before* any other command (such as activating the form). You'll need to post full code.